# How to avoid Spring Data Rest throwing HTTP 400 when an AccessDeniedException occurs on a controller

Tags: spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a spring data rest application with a simple one-to-many relationship.

(1 organization contains zero or more employees).

In a scenario without any security, I can add employees to the organization like this :

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"name":"name1","organization":"http://localhost:8080/api/organizations/1"}'  http://localhost:8080/api/employee
```

When the employee payload is pushed to the rest controller, Spring Data Rest will convert the organization uri  to an organization entity, hook it up to the employee, and everything works fine.

However, suppose I start securing my organization API and I only want to allow authorized users to see an organization (based on some business logic).

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface OrganizationController extends CrudRepository<Organization, Long> {

    @PreAuthorize("@securityService.isAllowedToSeeTheOrganization(#id)")
    Organization findOne(@P("id") Long id);

}
```

The SecurityService implements some business logic to determine if the user is able to retrieve an organization based on his profile :

```
@Service
public class SecurityService {

    public boolean isAllowedToSeeOrganization(Long organizationId) {
        return isAdmin() || belongsToOrganization(organizationId);
    }

    private boolean isAdmin() {
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ADMIN.getRoleName()));
    }

    private boolean belongsToOrganization(Long organizationId) {
        return organizationId == Long.parseLong(getUserDetails().get(ORGANIZATION_ID_FIELD).toString());

    }

    protected Map<String,Object> getUserDetails() {
        JwtAuthentication jwtAuthentication = (JwtAuthentication) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return jwtAuthentication.getJwtClaimsSet().getClaims();
    }

}
```

This off course will also have an effect on the call above, as it will no longer be able to convert the organization uri into an entity.

However, instead of throwing a 403 Forbidden, the API call fails with an HTTP 400 (Bad Request) and the following body:

```
{
    "cause":{
        "cause":{
            "cause":null,
            "message":"Access is denied"
        },
        "message":"Access is denied (through reference chain: com.example.Employee[\"organization\"])"
    },
    "message":"Could not read document: Access is denied (through reference chain: com.example.Employee[\"organization\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Access is denied (through reference chain: com.example.Employee[\"organization\"])"
}
```

In the logs :

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Access is denied (through reference chain: com.example.Employee["organization"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:388) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:348) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1599) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:359) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:148) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3798) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2922) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:237) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 97 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:65) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy156.findOne(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.invoke(ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.java:265) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.invokeFindOne(ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.java:140) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.CrudRepositoryInvoker.invokeFindOne(CrudRepositoryInvoker.java:91) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory$UnwrappingRepositoryInvoker.invokeFindOne(UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.java:130) ~[spring-data-rest-core-2.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.core.UriToEntityConverter.convert(UriToEntityConverter.java:123) ~[spring-data-rest-core-2.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$UriStringDeserializer.deserialize(PersistentEntityJackson2Module.java:516) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:499) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:101) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:357) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
```

The fact that it leaks internal information back to the client makes me think there is something wrong.

I would simply like the api to return a 403 Forbidden in this case, or have some way of customising this error message.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Could you share the code of securityService, employee and spring security config? Seems that there is some error in JSON mapping, that's why 400 is thrown.

Comment: Added the stacktrace / securtity service implementation. Data Rest Uri / Entity converter triggers a repository call. The authentication object isn't allowed to do that call (PreAuthorize), and the AccessDeniedException is thrown. AccessDeniedException gets pushed up the stack and Spring throws an http 400 to the client. I would still expect a 403 instead of a 400  here.

Answer (score 1):

Naturally you should use the standard [Spring exception handling mechanisms](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) but your problem is a bit more complicated than usually. I've tried my solution on a demo project and this should work.

In your case the `AccessDeniedException` is wrapped in a `JsonMappingException`, which itself is wrapped in a `HttpMessageNotReadableException`. This is what Spring exception handling gets:

```
HttpMessageNotReadableException
|---JsonMappingException
    |---AccessDeniedException
```

According to [this ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14291) in the Spring issue tracker `@ExceptionHandler` methods can match wrapped Exceptions since Spring 4.3, but only up to one level deep. Using an `@ExceptionHandler` for `AccessDeniedException` won't work because it's nested two levels below the exception Spring has received.

You could alter how deep in the exception chain Spring is looking for matching handlers, but if it's only for this problem i'd just define an exception handler that does that:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> accessDenied(Exception e) throws Exception {
        Throwable cause = e.getCause();
        if (cause != null) {
            Throwable nestedCause = cause.getCause();
            if (AccessDeniedException.class.isAssignableFrom(nestedCause.getClass())) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
            }
        }
        throw e;
    }
}
```

You could customise the matching (maybe search the complete exception chain for the wanted exception?) and add a return message.

Note that the handler is defined in its own class - since your EmployeeController presumably is an interface, like your OrganizationController, the @ExceptionHandler method can't be defined inside it (default method doesn't work either).